# Waiting for Query Params before Sending Api Call

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Trying to use some url parameters in an API call. Eventually my plan is to allow the user to put in a Zip Code and I will transform the zip code into latitude and longitude. This is intended to be a digital signage solution where the user can set up a URL in their signage system and include their location as part of the url.

Here's what I have for my created function in Vue. Admittedly, I am both a novice at Vue and still trying to fully understand async await. I thought that I did, but this is inconsistently not waiting for the latitude and longitude params from the query before sending the API call.

```
async created() {
    const lat = await this.$route.query.lat;
    const lon = await this.$route.query.lon;
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
          'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon + '&units=imperial&exclude=minutely,alerts&appid=' + process.env.VUE_APP_APIKEY,
          { headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"} }
      )
      this.weather = response.data
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.toJSON());
    }
  }
```

Current Updated code using setup

```
setup() {
    const route = useRoute();
    let lat = ref(0);
    let lon = ref(0);
    let weather = ref(null);


    watchEffect(() => {
      lat.value = route.query.lat;
      console.log(lat.value);
      lon.value = route.query.lon;
      console.log(lon.value);

      axios.get(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=' + lat.value + '&lon=' + lon.value + '&units=imperial&exclude=minutely,alerts&appid=' + process.env.VUE_APP_APIKEY,
        { headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"} }
      ).then( response => {
        weather.value = response.data;
        console.log(weather);
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
    });

    return {
      lat, lon, weather
    }
  },
```

Comment: Have you tried `mounted()` method instead of `created()`? Also `await` mustn't be used for properties, `const lat = this.$route.query.lat;` is enough.

Comment: I have not tried mounted() in a while. I’ll give that a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing this in either the `watch` function (both in the options and the composition API) or a `watchEffect` (only in the composition API), the latter is less complicated. It just listens to changes on reactive properties.

```
<script setup>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue';

const route = useRoute();

const lat = ref(0);
const long = ref(0);

watchEffect(() => {
  lat.value = route.query.lat;
  lng.value = route.query.lng;
});
</script>
```

You will need to better safeguard the assignments!

Comment: Thanks for your response! Sorry, I’m still a bit confused how this helps me make sure that  the API call doesn’t get run before the values from the url parameters are assigned. Could you explain that a bit. I’m not having any issues getting my url parameters, the API call just isn’t waiting.

Comment: You could simply call it in the `watch` function. The way you made it's only listening to the `created` event -- wouldn't recommend that, but rather in the `mounted` function. What I'm suggesting is a little more robust because if user's change the query (without a route change) the mount function won't be called again. The `watchEffect` should call it on **every** change. Within that effect you can call you api and transform the function to an `async` one. A change can be between two bookmarks for example.

Comment: Ok, I think I am starting to understand this. I have it working at some level. My issue now is that both `lat.value` and `lon.value` are undefined the first time watchEffect runs. That in turn causes the API call to fail because of the undefined values. It then gets rerun once `lat.value` and `lon.value` get updated and the API call suceeds. I would like to avoid the initial failed API call.

See updated code sample in original post. Thanks

Comment: I mentioned that you need to safeguard it. So you need to determine when you want to call the API, pseudo code: `watchEffect(() => { if(isFloat(lat.value) && isFloat(lng.value)) { callApi() } }`. Within the `watchEffect` you can literally do anything and it will listen to any changes of reactive variables used within it. Thus everytime a reactive variable that is used in the `watchEffect` is changed, the function will execute. Do note that this is only available in Vue 3.

Comment: Thank Maarten for explaining things well for me. I believe I have this working adequately for now and have a better understanding of these concepts now. Appreciate your help!